# Unable to directly edit DBF files in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, database

I often use QGIS and need to edit DBF files asociated with the shapefile layers. I am used to do it in LibreOffice and it always worked on Windows and I think it also worked in older versions of Kubuntu.

Unfortunately I found out that currently the LibreOffice Calc opens the DBF file but saves not just the DBF but DBF + DBT file instead. The DBT file seems to contain all the data and QGIS reports damaged data.

Is there any way to solve it (install some additional library, set something...)? I currently installed Gnumeric which should be able to perform the editing but would prefer Calc if possible.

Comment: What happens when you save your file using Libreofice Base